# Retrieving data from a variable through http request

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I am new to http request and php. I have a http:

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
       if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
         var doc = xmlhttp.response;
         myFunc(doc);
       }
   };
   xmlhttp.open("GET",some.php",true);
   xmlhttp.responseType = "document";
   xmlhttp.send(null);
```

The php file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title></title>
      </head>
      <body id="idk">
        <?php
        include("include1.inc");
        include_once("include2.inc");

        $cxn = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$passwd,$dbname) or die("Could not connect to the server at this time.");
        $table = 'table';

        $data = retrieveData($table, $cxn);//selects data from mysql db return array
        var_dump($data);

         ?>
      </body>
    </html>
```

How would I get the data variable which holds my array from my database?
When i dump or print the variable the array is passed `responseText. Is there a more eloquent way to just grab that array?

Comment: Font color says you forgot quotes.

Comment: `xmlhttp.open("GET",some.php",true);` => `xmlhttp.open("GET","some.php",true);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You sets response type as 'document', so you'll get HTMLDocument onbject as a response. So if you need to get only data variable try change your code this way:
javascript:

```
   xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
       if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
         var doc = xmlhttp.response;
         myFunc(doc);
       }
   };
   xmlhttp.open("GET","some.php",true);
   xmlhttp.responseType = "json";
   xmlhttp.send();
```

And php:

```
<?php
        include("include1.inc");
        include_once("include2.inc");

        $cxn = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$passwd,$dbname) or die("Could not connect to the server at this time.");
        $table = 'table';

        $data = retrieveData($table, $cxn);//selects data from mysql db return array
        echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

Please, note that in this case php script doesn't contain any html tag, only php code.

Comment: This worked perfectly @user1722564. This converts my $data variable into a json object to allow me to manipulate it and retrieve the info out it.